# GCP VM ECONNREFUSED with completely open firewalls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, firewall

I have a few gcp virtual machines setup with external IPs and http/https turned on.

Also added completely open firewall ingress/egress rules...[image]

However when I try to reach the external IP it refuses to connect.

Here is the result of running `netstat -a`

[image]

Also when describing my instance I can verify it is running and setup on http/https firewall

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that your services on the VM are running, respond to localhost, and bind to 0.0.0.0? Your question has few details. Show the tests that you have performed to verify your services are working correctly on the VM. Then debug public access.

Comment: @JohnHanley what tests? the processes are running on all four instances

Comment: OK, the processes are running. What are they listening to? Your question lacks details.

Comment: @JohnHanley added the results of running netstat -a on the instance. However I'm confused since my initial screenshot shows the firewall should allow public traffic from any port

Comment: You do not have an HTTP server running. VPC firewalls allow traffic. They do not create services on your system that responds to connections.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the specific port to the request url. In my case it was

```
JSONRPC_URL=http://EXTERNAL-IP:8545
```